# checkboxlistfor does not work even on adding its dll in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkboxlist

I am following this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC to create checkboxlistFor in my MVC4 project but even after following all steps it gives an error that "The type or namespace name 'Model' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcCheckBoxList' "

I have added the MvcCheckBoxList dll, recomplied the application and added the model at the top i.e. *@using MvcCheckBoxList.Model* but no success. Did anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: I'm guessing that just a typo and it should be just `@using MvcCheckBoxList`

Comment: I tried removing Model but now, it gives error message for MvcCheckBoxList i.e. The type or namespace name 'MvcCheckBoxList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. The issue was that if we add the MvcCheckBoxList dll manually then this error is observed. However, if we install its package from Nuget then it works correctly.